# Is it possible to show current active user count inside the app in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to show in my app, how many users are online. I tried to find solutions but the solutions that i found is generally in web, i have mobile app and i want to show how many users are online. Can someone please help?

Comment: what does online mean ? it probably means _connected_ to your server, right ?

Comment: I'm talking about users who have opened the app on their phone and haven't closed the app yet.

Comment: This would be a matter of setting a flag in Firebase to indicate the user is using the app. You can then query firebase for active users (who have the flag set) or use an observer to automatically notify you of an active user.

Answer (score 2):

From the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). Firebase has the functionality to monitor presence in the application. RTDB supports it natively, but Firestore leverages other services to implement it.

Comment: That's indeed the approach I'd recommend, but I'd start directly from the Realtime Database version of this, instead of from the Firestore wrapper around it. The Android [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) are a good starting point, as they should map fairly directly to Flutter.